# Problem 1.b, Section 3.2, Introduction to Real Analysis, Bartle

Tags: real-analysis

$x_n = (-1)^n .\frac{n}{n + 1}$

Convergent or divergent?

I computed the limit of $\frac{n}{n + 1}$, which is $1$, and from the book we know that $(-1)^n$ is divergent. Does this mean that the sequence $x_n$ is divergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but that's not quite sufficient justification: If you multiply terms in a divergent sequence with terms in a convergent sequence, the result doesn't need to be divergent.

---

To show it's divergent, try computing $X_n$ for $n$ even and $n$ odd separately - then we have two subsequences converging to different limits, which is not possible for a convergent sequence.

Comment: Ok, so, you're saying that I need to say then that when n is even, we have n/(n + 1), which converges at 1, and when n is odd, we have -n/(n + 1), which converges to -1. Thus, sequence is divergent. Is this sufficient?

Comment: @user129360 Assuming you can use that result, then yes: You're done.